# I need to replace url 'profiles' to customname

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to replace url 'profiles' to customname on wordpress template. i.e. mysite.com/profiles to become mysite.com/customname but to load the same page, its like I'm just translating it.

How can I achieve that ?

Comment: what kind of web server you are using?

Comment: I'm using apache server.